# How can I make these clouds 100% opaque

Tags: texturing, shader-nodes

I'm trying to create a late evening scene with clouds on the horizon, and I need the background volumetric clouds to be grey and opaque, but I can't find any way of doing it other than making them black.
[image: Camera view of skyline and cloud shader node tree]

Is there a way of making these clouds fully opaque without being completely black?

Comment: Fully opaque? Well, use a _Principled BSDF_ and instead of controlling the density, use the textures to drive the _Alpha_ value. But even then you will have the problem that the clouds are backlit. If you want them to appear grey, you need a light shining on their front side.

Comment: You could add a math multiply node to lower the density. Or increase the emission

Comment: @Chris Lowering the density makes them more opaque?